# actionscript 3: calling function for second time wont work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to actionscript 3, I have sequences of frames and two buttons to control which sequence to play, it first works properly, but have problem when a sequence is being played for the second time. I have used gotoAndPlay function for my navigation. can anyone help me?

Comment: Post code to get help.

Comment: I have little codes on some of my frames like:

stop();

buttonHigh.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_11);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 gotoAndPlay(48);
 }


buttonLow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_12);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_12(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 gotoAndPlay(96);
}
and some other codes exactly like this but with different navigation frame numbers.

Comment: Your code seems fine, but the error also depends on what you have on frame 48 and frame 96, timeline coding is very annoying. post more about how you set-up your button. Click on edit in your post and post more code and detail about what you are doing.

Comment: thank you for your response, I think I've found my answer... the problem was with my eventListeners! I removed them before my "gotoAndPlay" and its nearly ok!
now the only problem is that it skips some sequences!

Answer (score 0):

From your description I have a hunch about what may be happening...

Firstly I would ask you if the buttons are present at all frames along the timeline? If they are not (ie, sometimes the timeline shows a frame where the buttons are not present before returning to them ) you should realise that when they come back into view again, they are *not the same buttons* as the ones from before. That means that the event listeners you attached the first time are not going to respond to clicks on these *new* buttons.

This happens because flash always totally recreates timeline objects when they come into view again. Flash can sometimes cope with a "jump" over a "gap" when a symbol is the same, but this is extremely unreliable and should be avoided for this reason.

You can avoid this problem by keeping the ui on the stage at all times, and revealing and hiding the buttons when you need them. Even better, create an instance of your ui in code and add it to the stage when you need it. This way you know there is only one instance, and you are in control of it.